# jQuery shows wrong p index

Tags: jquery

So I made a small example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4yz7b7L/

Which shows that p element has 2 index, instead of 0 (then hovering on first p element). Why is that so ?

```
$('body').on('hover', '.trn p', function() {
var ind = $(this).index();
var ps = $('.trn:visible p:eq(' + ind + ')').html();
console.log(ps);
console.log(ind);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure looks like this:

```
<div class="trn">
    <img />
    <h1></h1> 
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

So the first `<p>` is the third item inside the parent. Indexes start with 0, so the third item has index 2.

Instead of using the index, why not use `$(this)`?

```
$('body').on('hover', '.trn p', function() {
   var ind = $(this).index();
   var ps = $(this).html();
   console.log(ps);
   console.log(ind);
});
```

Comment: What if I want to get index of p elements in parent, excluding all other elements ?

Comment: Then use `var ind = $('.trn p').index( $(this) );` [More info in the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$(this)` or `$(event.target)` which is the same in the end :

```
$('body').on('hover', '.trn p', function(event) {
    var ps1 = $(this).html(),
        ps2 = $(event.target).html();
    console.log(ps1);
    console.log(ps2);
});
```